# Multiple domains pointing to the same server/directory and using php to handle what will be rendered depending on the domain entered?

Tags: php

I want to point multiple domain names to the same server/directory, then, using PHP I will detect what domain name have been entered in the URL and finally it will render content related to that domain.

It is okay with the best practices to do that?

Example, I will create two websites using the same backend code to handle things on the server side but the front-end will be different with different domain names.

Comment: in my opinion, this is best done with a capable http server (like apache), and associate each routed domain to a virtual host. Each vhost can have an http and https handler. If you are trying to service secure web domains, you can have appropriate certificates for each domain, declared in the domain's vhost file, each domain independent from the others.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect what domain they're coming in on with

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

and then load the appropriate file accordingly. For example, if you have example1.com and example2.com routed to the same server, then

```
if ('example1.com' == $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    require('file1.php');
} elseif ('example2.com' == $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    require('file2.php');
}
```

will load file1.php or file2.php depending.

Comment: Thx @wogsland , but I know how to get the domain name from the URL. I just want to know if doing what I said above is "okay" with the best practices since I have never done this kind of handling before. :)